# Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON on AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax call for updating data, but on `JSON.stringfy(params)` Error appearing `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`   I am using multiple parameters, some are plane text and one parameters contain array List. may be this is region i am getting this Error.

Can any one help me

**how to pass Multiple Parameters some of plane data and one Array List in Ajax call jquery**

If I do same, This will solve my problem.

I am using `Devexpress` Control for multi selection of Plant Items `(ASPx DropdownEdit with ASPxListBox for multiple selection of Items)` for Plant Code

I tried making prams parameters as Array but still no successs

```
var PlantCode = {};
PlantCode = checkListBox.GetSelectedItems();
```

**AJAX**

```
var PlantCode = {};
PlantCode = checkListBox.GetSelectedItems();
var params = {
                'UserID' : $('#txtUserIDEdit').val(), 'UserName' : $('#txtUserNameEdit').val(),
                'Password': $('#txtPassword').val(), 'Status': $("input[name='Status']:checked").val(),
                'CreatedBy' : $('#txtUserNameEdit').val(),
                'LocationCode' : PlantCode
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                url: 'MobileUser_Login.aspx/UpdateRecord',
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.error) {
                        alert('Update Successfully !!');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**I tried**

```
var UID = $('#txtUserIDEdit').val();
var UName = $('#txtUserNameEdit').val();
var Pass = $('#txtPassword').val();
var St = $("input[name='Status']:checked").val();
var CrtdBy = $('#txtUserNameEdit').val();
var PlantCode = checkListBox.GetSelectedItems();
    var AllData = {
        UserID: UID,
        UserName: UName,
        Password: Pass,
        Status: St,
        CreatedBy: CrtdBy,
        LocationCode: PlantCode  // Array List
      }

         var ApplObj = { ApplicantDetail: AllData };
```

As we i can see array is storing record as expected in this screen shots i have selected 2 List items so its showing array length is 2.

[image]
What is wrong i have done kindly help me.

Comment: What is the `checkListBox` object?

Comment: Chances are, the error is coming from `PlantCode`. What is it! How are you constructing the “array list” as you have commented in the code?

Comment: Plant Code is ASPX DropdownEdit  control